# Crashlytics NDK failes to parse NDK crash data

Tags: android, android-ndk, crashlytics

I'm building an Android application supporting native build via ndk.
Furthermore I use Crashlytics NDK in order to get crash reports for jni and cpp crashes. 
Sometimes it happens that the Crashlytics NDK fails to send a crash report for crashes in cpp classes (java and jni work like a charm).

```
08-13 09:45:05.690  25875-25996/? E/CrashlyticsNdk﹕ Failed to parse NDK crash data.
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
        at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
        at com.crashlytics.android.ndk.JsonCrashDataParser.parseCrashEventData(JsonCrashDataParser.java:73)
        at com.crashlytics.android.ndk.CrashlyticsNdk.doInBackground(CrashlyticsNdk.java:117)
        at com.crashlytics.android.ndk.CrashlyticsNdk.doInBackground(CrashlyticsfNdk.java:23)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

It seems to be a bug in crashlytics ndk framework.

The following versions are in use:

```
com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.0@aar
com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.1@aar
```

Crashlytics Gradle config:

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut '$buildDir/../obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut '$buildDir/../libs'
}
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Interestingly the log that it is trying to pass is empty: 

    End of input at character 0 of...

Im also seeing this issue now. Did you ever get around to fixing this?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no new release fixing this bug. The Crashlytics team also can't give an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be fixed by a new release of crashlytics ndk (v1.1.2).
See the response from support:

> I have some great news! We found the root cause to this issue and the fix was just released in 1.1.2. It'd be great to have you upgrade and try it out.
>   Let me know how it goes!

Comment: I'm using `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.2@aar` and I still see this problem

Comment: @mp251 I agree with you. I'm also seeing this issue in 1.1.2